# Nginx rewrite with query

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I need to convert this 301 redirect to a nginx rewrite

```
Redirect 301 /details.php?floorID=123 http://www.example.com/flooring.html
```

I tried this and it works:

```
rewrite ^/details.php /flooring.html permanent;
```

but when I add the variables it does not recognise anything after the ?

This is what I need, but it does not work:

```
rewrite ^/details.php?floorID=123 /flooring.html permanent;
```

Can anyone advise?

Thanks

Comment: Why you want it in nginx?

Comment: because their hosting is set to ignore .htaccess files

Comment: This should be done in app.

Comment: It seems this does not work as I'm unable to use location (due to the way Plesk is handling each domain) hence my original post shows the rewrite that does work.

     `location /details.php?floorID=123 {
rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/flooring.html redirect;
}`

I assume my issue is that I need the correct expressions. But re-writes are not my forte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
if ($query_string ~ "^floorID=123"){
    rewrite ^/?details.php$ /flooring.html? permanent;
}
```